# View snapshot not being saved in photos

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

I tried googling and looking at other relevant questions in SO, however, I have not been able to fix this issue: I am using this piece of code to take snapshot of the entire screen (ios7). However, no images are being saved. I tried logging out data sizes, dimensions,etc. They seem to be valid. Any pointers?

```
    UIView *screenshotView = [[UIScreen mainScreen] snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates:NO];
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(screenshotView.bounds.size);
    [[screenshotView layer] renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *scrnshot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(scrnshot, nil, nil, nil);
```

Comment: Did you try actually using the completion selector to see if there was an error instead of just passing nil as every parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(scrnshot, self, @selector(image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);
```

And implement this method in your controller:

```
- (void)image:(UIImage *)image didFinishSavingWithError:(NSError *)error contextInfo:(void *)contextInfo {

        if (error) {
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Error" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];

            [alert show];
        }
        else {
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done" message:@"Image saved successfully" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];

            [alert show];
        }
    }
```

Either it'll work, or you'll figure out what the problem is.
Make sure you allowed your app to use the photo library.

Hope it works.

UPDATE:

I use this code to take screenshot:

```
CGSize screenSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame].size;
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpaceRef = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(); 
CGContextRef ctx = CGBitmapContextCreate(nil, screenSize.width, screenSize.height, 8, 4*(int)screenSize.width, colorSpaceRef, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);
CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, 0.0, screenSize.height);
CGContextScaleCTM(ctx, 1.0, -1.0);

[(CALayer*)self.view.layer renderInContext:ctx];

CGImageRef cgImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(ctx);
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgImage];
CGImageRelease(cgImage);
CGContextRelease(ctx);  
[UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0) writeToFile:@"screen.jpg" atomically:NO];
```

Hope it works with you!

Comment: Thanks Bem, I already had an alert implemented, did not include it in the code I posted

Comment: I am not getting any errors and the picture is saved successfully. However, it is all white. My app background is white, but I was expecting the status bar(which is not hidden) to show up in the snapshot. Any idea why this is not happening?

Answer (score -1):

Actually, images are saving in photo library, but they are in **WHITE** color. That's why it seems that there is no image.
 You need to change this line `UIView *screenshotView = [[UIScreen mainScreen] snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates:NO];` and your code will work fine.

Comment: Downvote with a comment or reason would be appreciated.

Comment: Just noticed that images are being saved, all white. When you wrote change this line...., what did you propose to change that line to?

Comment: It depends on your requirement. You can change it to UIView *screenshotView = self.View; and it will work. It's working for me.